# netbeans: copy new/modified source files by run configuration

Tags: deployment, netbeans

I'm testing netbeans 7 over our good old eclipse. We have a local workspace (c:\workspace), a svn server somewhere in the network, and 3 servers: dev, test, prod.

For each server, there is a local "source" copy in a local dir on the webserver.

In eclipse, When I want to "test" something I deploy all files I need from the "syncrhonize" panel on "test" server, using eclipse "export" panel. (And then open the test web page). Sometimes I "deploy" some files for a coworker to test them, or vice versa. I like to do this from the "synchronise" panel because you can easily see and ctrl+select all changed files/folders you need to export to the destination server. Higly practical (not like in a five-screens-long explorer).

In netbeans, there are "run configurations" which allow to define the webserver page (http://test.com/index.html). However, I can't define the webserver "source". When I try to use path mapping for this, files ain't copied at "runtime" (F6). there is no way to export/deploy files to a specific location from the "versioning output" window (like in eclipse).

Actually, i plan to use netbeans for "programming", and eclipse to "export" files.  Does anybody have a more practical solution within netbeans?

**EDIT** 2 days later... and we decided to stay with eclipse, mainly for this reason. (and some preferred search results in folders and not in a flat list). Plus we never got xdebug to work when the server was on another host than local. However, i will keep a hidden version of netbeans, mainly for refactoring/cleansing. It detects "semi valid" html and unused variables/functions way better than eclipse.

Comment: I highly recommend that you stop depending on your IDE environment to do stuff for you.  Configure and use a repeatable process (if you're developing in Java, then something like Ant or Maven) that you know works no matter the environment.  Doing something like this will assist you when you decide in the future to bring a Continuous Integration server into the mix.

Comment: php here. Anyway, ant is hardly an option, as most of time I need to deploy some, *but not all* of my "checked out" files. (when I'm asked to do a quickfix on files I'm not working on atm). We would like to keep that flexibility.